# Change an HTML <p> tag value to an empty value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to replace a content in a p tag by  an empty value(" ")(in case there was a value entered by the user in this p tag) when i check a checkbox in javascript.

**Html /javascript:**

```js
$('.checkboxesmodel1').change(function() {
  var option2and1_model1 = $("#option2and1_model1");
  var divall = document.querySelector('.options');
  if (($('#id_model1_option2').prop('checked')) && ($('#id_model1_option1').prop('checked'))) {
    option2and1_model1.hide();
    divall.querySelector('p').innerText = '';
  } else if (($('#id_model1_option2').prop('checked'))) {
    option2and1_model1.show();
  } else if (($('#id_model1_option1').prop('checked'))) {
    option2and1_model1.hide();
    divall.querySelector('p').innerText = '';
  } else {
    option2and1_model1.hide();
    divall.querySelector('p').innerText = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
#Div Code of the checkboxes
<div id="tblmodel1options">
  <label for="id_model1_option1">
        <img  id="tinypic_2"
          src="{% static 'img/MODEL1OPTION 1.png' %}"/>
        <div class="checkboxesmodel1" >
          <input name = "model1_option1" id="id_model1_option1" type="checkbox"     autocomplete="off" />   
        </div>
      </label>

  <label for="id_model1_option2">
        <img id="tinypic_3"
          src="{% static 'img/MODEL1OPTION 2.png' %}" />
        <div  class="checkboxesmodel1" >
          <input name = "model1_option2" type="checkbox" id="id_model1_option2" autocomplete="off" />    
        </div>
      </label>
</div>
#Div Code of the form fields
<div id="option2and1_model1" class="options">
  <p id="id_c"><strong>c:</strong>{{ form.c}} mm</p>
  <p id="id_h"><strong>h:</strong>{{ form.h}} mm</p>
</div>
```

----->THos code javascript doesn't give me any result

Comment: Is there an error in your console?

Comment: Why do you have `autocomplete="off"` in a checkbox? There's nothing to complete.

Comment: Your code seems to work in the snippet.

Comment: You empty the `<p>` in all the conditions of the `if`. What's the point of `if` when you do the same thing in all cases?

Comment: `" "` is not an empty value, it's a space character. To specify no value for a string, you use `""`.

Comment: @Barmar , I just added a part of code that doesn't work with me(empty the value entred by the user in case he change his choice of checkboxes) , I have 2 checkboxes a and b ,  in global i want when i check a checkbox "b" , there was new some fields appear where the user will enter some values and if he change then his mind and check the other checkbox the field value will be hidden and empty (the value entered initially in the previous one).

Comment: @Scott Marcus thanks but it doesn't work with me.

Comment: @HelenaCasteneda I don't see your added code yet.

Comment: @Barmar, I have edited the code , you can check it again , thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with what it's doing? `divall.querySelector("p")` only selects the first `<p>`. Is that what you want, or do you want both of them? Use `divall.querySelectorAll("p")` to get both of them, then use a `forEach()` loop to update them both. Or use jQuery `$(".options p").html("")` to empty all of them.

Comment: @Barmar , yeah i want both of them by deleting their values if their was some values writted by the user and then he change his mind..

Comment: I want to cleart he content of the <p> tag exit in the div (divall) in case  i change the checkbox choosed --